# Sorting Office 365 user account / mailbox properties

Tags: powershell, office365

I'm accessing my cloud Office 365 Exchange Server via Powershell. Showing all properties of an account can be done via `Get-Mailbox 'username' | Select *` ([MS reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-mailbox?view=exchange-ps)).

On most systems those properties are already sorted (e.g. `Get-ADUser 'username' -Properties *`). Is it possible to sort the `Get-Mailbox` output? I thought `Get-Mailbox 'username' | Select * | Sort-Object` would do the trick but it didn't make any difference (I guess a property doesn't constitute an object). What's the right command to sort the properties for a single user?

Note: Sorting properties of multiple accounts works fine e.g. `Get-Mailbox -filter * | select Name, DisplayName | Sort-Object Displayname`

**Update:**
I managed to get a sorted properties list using

```
(Get-Mailbox 'mailboxname' | select *).PSObject.properties | ForEach-Object {$_.Name} | Sort-Object Name
```

it gets me the following output:

```
AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom
AccountDisabled
AddressBookPolicy
ArchiveWarningQuota
...
```

`$_.Name` gives me the values but so far I couldn't combine both into one list, I'm trying to get s.th. like this:

```
AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom = {}
AccountDisabled = False
AddressBookPolicy = 
ArchiveWarningQuota = 45 GB (48,318,382,080 bytes)
...
```

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I think there was a missunderstanding, I want to list all the properties of a **single** mailbox object. The problem is: when I use the `Get-Mailbox 'mailboxname' | Select *`  command it gives me a list of all properties for that specific mailbox but the list is unsorted.

Comment: Right so, `Get-Mailbox 'mailboxname'` will return just 1 _object_ of the type `Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.Management.Mailbox` not a ___list___, if you want to sort it's properties, say alphabetically, you would need to discover them with `PSObject.Properties.Name` into `Sort-Object` into `Select-Object`.

Comment: The cmdlet also has a `-SortBy` parameter now that I'm looking at the MS Docs, this might be what you are after.

Comment: I noticed `-SortBy`, but as far as I understand it's used to sort multiple mailbox objects by a property?! How can it be used to sort all properties of a single object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not completely sure this is what you are after, let me know if I'm wrong. As in my comment, `Sort-Object` can handle sorting a *list* or an `object[]` by one or more of it's properties; but sorting one single object by it's properties, say alphabetically, would require a combination of accessing the object's properties with [`.PSObject.Properties.Name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.2) and then sorting this *list* with `Sort-Object`. And after that we can use `Select-Object` with this sorted list to display the object as we want.

Using the object below as an example as I have no idea how of the type `Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.Management.Mailbox` looks.

```
$mailbox = [pscustomobject]@{
    DisplayName = 'someuser'
    UserPrincipalName = 'someuser@somedomain.com'
    Mail = 'someuser@somedomain.com'
    IsLicensed = $true
}

$properties = $mailbox.PSObject.Properties.Name | Sort-Object

$mailbox | Select-Object $properties
```

As you can see, object's properties are now sorted alphabetically:

```
DisplayName IsLicensed Mail                    UserPrincipalName
----------- ---------- ----                    -----------------
someuser          True someuser@somedomain.com someuser@somedomain.com
```

---

By looking at your edit, seems like you are looking for a one-liner, so this is how it could look:

```
Get-Mailbox 'mailboxname' | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | Select-Object ($_.PSObject.Properties.Name | Sort-Object)
}
```

Comment: Worked fine, I used `$mailbox = (Get-Mailbox 'mailboxname' | select *)`, `$properties = (Get-Mailbox 'mailboxname' | select *).PSObject.Properties.Name | Sort-Object` and `$mailbox | Select-Object $properties`, just have to figure now, why this works... ;)

Comment: Ah, ok, I see... I created a sorted list of the properties names and then selected those proberties from the object... s.t. I find it a bit difficult to wrap my head around the PS syntax...

Comment: @Albin I looked at your edit, I think you want to do it as a oneliner, so you could use that one if you wanted

Comment: yeah, the one liner works great too, I just don't understand how it work, could you elaborate on it?

Comment: @Albin well you have explained it very well on your second comment, that's exactly what the code is doing

Comment: ok, so it's basically the same as the first solution. But why do you need `ForEach-Object` in there if `get-mailbox` only returns one object in our example anyway?

Comment: @Albin it's there so we have access to the object returned by `Get-Mailbox` through the pipeline ( `$_` ), having access to `$_` aka `$PSItem` gives you the ability to pass it through the pipeline to `Select-Object` and also to use it one more time on the `Sort-Object` part of the code. This is not something easy to grasp if you're just learning PS, it's a bit more advanced concept so I can understand if it's giving you trouble.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240488/discussion-between-albin-and-santiago-squarzon).